# how to delete data within a looped data

Tags: postgresql

Please can someone help on how to do this.
I have a log table as below where i am deleting all tables beyond 3 months.
Now i want add another step to clear the log table as well when the above step has been actioned. Example: drop the table if > 90 days then delete the associated rows from the log table too.

thanks

> ```
>        ddl_date           ddl_tag     ID  object_name
> 2022-07-07 16:40:06   CREATE FOREIGN  1   raj.auth
> 2022-02-07 17:14:33   CREATE TABLE    6   john.plots_source
> 2022-03-07 17:14:33   CREATE TABLE    7   john.plots1
> 2022-04-07 17:14:33   CREATE TABLE    8   johnb.plots_pkey2
> 2022-05-07 17:14:33   CREATE TABLE    9   johna.plots_address3
> ```

```
DO $$ 
  DECLARE 
    r RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN 
    (
      SELECT id, object_name from user_monitor.ddl_history WHERE ddl_date < NOW() - INTERVAL '90 days'
    ) 
  LOOP
     EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || r.object_name || ' CASCADE';
  END LOOP;
 delete from user_monitor.ddl_history where not exists (select tablename from pg_catalog.pg_tables b where r.object_name = b.tablename);
     commit;
END $$ ;
```

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: query has no destination for result data
> Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM
> instead.   Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 12 at SQL
> statement

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing r.object_name outside of the LOOP.

Try pulling the DELETE statement inside the LOOP so that "r" is a valid reference that can cycle among all cursor values within the execution context.